# Solving Traveling Salesman-like Problem

Tags: google-maps-api, topology, route

I own a (very) small appliance service company. It's just me. I cover roughly a 20 mile radius from a my office.

Customers can sign up on my website for service calls anywhere within my service area. I use Google's Distance Matrix API to reject any calls that are more than 20 miles or 30 minutes from my office.

Generally this works pretty well, however sometimes I'll get a call at the far east border of my area, followed by a call at the far west border, followed by another call at the far east border, which is much more wasted time and miles than I want to allow.

The question is "how do I detect and define 'the same area'" so I can refuse or reschedule the call to eliminate driving all the way across the territory more than once a day?

I haven't been able to figure out how to tell if I'm covering the same *general* area (for example, the northwest corner of the county) more than once a day.

Does anybody have any suggestions what I can do/look for and/or how I can define "same area" in a way that would be useful for routing?

Just to make things more complicated, the area is loaded with lakes and rivers, so a location that's 1000' away on the other side of some water geography might be an hour or more drive.

**UPDATE - Where practice and theory collided**

Initially, I tried a floating window over the "last location visited" but a small window excluded too many customers and a larger window let the area covered "wander" across the state if customers happened to show up in order of their coordinates.

5 or 6 customers that happened to have a similar latitude and sequentially increasing or decreasing longitude (or the other way around) could leave me driving across large portions of the state, which was exactly what I was trying to eliminate.

So I implemented @nr-aus idea and just split the state into quadrants, within a maximum radius. This means the area for any particular day is known and acceptably small and that the location test for new customers becomes a couple of latitude/longitude checks.

It's quite practical and lightweight and has been working well.

Comment: How many calls a day on average? Can you visualize your trip?

Comment: I really like your question, a moving target driving distance is not easy to implement. Perhaps you could work something out with 'leave after' of driving directions https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/how-calculate-distances-map-maps-javascript-api as well as your existing geofence constraint. Another option is OpenStreetMap https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing if Google doesn't have a solution. If you come up with something that works please post as an answer to your own question, I'm sure there are many people with the same problem.

Comment: Please cut/paste your solution from the area reserved for questions into the area reserved for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an initial item, maybe just divide your entire operating area into smaller sub-areas, and work out some general business rules for travel.

eg: If in Utah, accept a job in Colorado, but not Ohio.

This would give you an initial 'ballpark' starting point to work with and would at least eliminate the worst case scenario's.

Comment: That's what I''ve come up with so far, however instead of having fixed areas like "east" and "west" I'm working on dynamically defined areas centered on the first call of the day.

Comment: yep yep, I like it....... With your first customer calculation, instead of buffering - you could program it such that it runs a 'max cost' travel route, and anyone not on that route cannot book in that time slot. You would need to run a 'trace out' network trace with a stop argument of X, X being your max distance. You could possibly generalise this data such that you just have street-suburb (as opposed to individual house numbers, data might get too big.

Answer (score 1):

Because it IS TSP problem, solution can be optimal or approximate. Picture below shows solution for 10 clients:

[image]

It is optimal solution because I used permutations to compute route, i.e. blunt force approach. It took 46 seconds and I ended up with total travel distance of 44 km.

In case I am willing to travel no more than 35 km, I have to exclude 2 clients:

[image]

I don't think that splitting service area in sub-units is going to work, for example see 2 neighbors in SW corner.

Algorithm I used to filter candidates is very simple:

- shuffle through candidates inserting one into original [SHOP,SHOP] list
- apply TSP algorithm with first and last stop being SHOP
- pick node that results in minimum travel increase and total distance is below limit, keep order in memory
- insert best node to travel schedule (originally it will make [SHOP,node,SHOP]) and remove it from candidates.
- break if no such node found or list of candidates is empty.

Line 2 is crucial, I cancel script after 5 minutes, when attempting to cover 11 clients **without** distance limit. However **with** distance limit it worked on larger lists:

[image]

so it is worth trying. I expect it will take too long to compute, when number of clients within legal limit will exceed 10.

If this is a frequent case, there are many approximate solutions for TSP, so perhaps try one that seems easiest to implement, because poor model is better than none.

Comment: While I can see that you put a lot of work into this, I don't think the answer fits the problem. You (I think) assume that I have a number of customers that I can rearrange; however this isn't the case.

The customers are allowed to pick the day and time they want, when they sign up. I'm looking for a way to disallow customers from adding themselves to schedules that would cause wasted driving.

It's not that I want to arrange the "east" and "west" customers optimally, I need to be able to recognize a new address that would make the day's route overly inefficient.

Comment: Well, if the first customer known it simplifies things significantly, because you can include only those  , that will keep total within your limit.

Comment: That's what I'm working on now. Still working out the kinks. The first customer is known. After that, I'm only allowing new customers that fit into a floating "window" of an acceptable distance from the first customer. Then I can move the floating window to the second customer, etc.

Comment: Again it is simple when 1st customer (A) is defined. Your TSP route is [Shop,A, Shop]. With 2nd (B) you'll have this dilemma to solve 
[Shop,A, B, Shop] or
[Shop,B,A, Shop]. If minimum of both greater travel limit, reject B, if not keep one of 2 lists (doesn't matter which, because final 
sequence might be different), etc. The only important thing is number of orders,
because when your 'keep' list exceeds 10, you'll need to replace permutations to solve TSP - best possible solution - by approximatation.
 Solution will be biased towards 1st address.

Answer (score 0):

- I allow the first customer for a day to pick any available time and location within my service area.
- Once the first call is scheduled, I block off all the available appointment time slots for that day except the slot adjacent before and adjacent after. This prevents a gap between calls which is one of the things that allows for inefficient routing.
- I then define a 120° wedge with the origin at my office and the curved end at the edge of my territory, with the customer at the 60° point (middle of the wedge)
- If another customer tries to sign up, the next available temporally adjacent schedule slot is made available, only if they are located within the wedge, and within the travel time I allow. If not, they're offered a different day. This handles cases like "one customer on east lake road" and the other on "west lake road", which without a boat, is an hour drive.

Essentially, I have a floating window 1/3 of my service area wide, centered on the first scheduled call, with travel time obtained from the Google Distance Matrix API to enable enforcing a maximum amount of drive time. This might need to be adjusted.

This does not generate any sort of "optimal" routing, since that wasn't the goal. The goal was to prevent "awful" routing, while still giving the customers significant control over the day and time for their appointment.